# Save editable PDFs using Java iText PDF API

Tags: java, api, pdf, itext

I'm experimenting with the iText5 library to generate an editable (i.e. allow user to enter values in fields like age, name etc) PDF, it looks like the user 
can't save the filled in PDF on his work station and the only available functionality is to take a printout of the filled in PDF form.

I tried googling this issue and found that with Adobe Reader, users can't save filled in forms and they need to have Acrobat Pro.

Is there any solution to get this job done (saving the filled in PDF form and emailing it) without needing to get Adobe Pro software?

Please feel free to ask me questions if the problem description is not clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are other viewers that allow people to save filled out forms locally (Nitro? Foxit?). In the early years, there were also people that used iText to create a mini server on the desktop to which the data filled out in Adobe Reader was sent. This server then returned the filled out form. Once Adobe found out about this practice, they changed the EULA of Adobe Reader, saying that you are not allowed to use Adobe Reader for this purpose.

Summarized:

- If you want a solution that involves your end users to use Adobe Reader: there is none. You'd violate the EULA of Adobe Reader.
- If it's OK to use a PDF viewer other than Adobe Reader: pick another viewer that allows saving of filled out forms.

Note: this is not an iText question.

Comment: Thanks Bruno for the quick response, it looks like none of those softwares (Nitro/Foxit) are free. I'm wondering how is everyone else is doing it? Is it mandated now to have acrobat pro as the prerequisite ? My requirement is very simple, generate a pdf report and have user to enter data in some fields and email the document, but I can't seem to have the entered data attached to email and it just contains whatever the data it was pre-populated earlier.

Comment: Er... iText isn't "for free" either, is it? See https://youtu.be/QHF3xcWnSD4 There is no way that I know of that allows you to do what you want without paying a software license. How do other people do it? They buy Adobe software to *Reader enable* a form. A Reader enabled form can be saved locally.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I think I will go ahead with iText 2.x which could serve my basic things well.

Comment: That's also a risk, because of the legal issues with that version. There used to be a question on SO explaining what is wrong with iText 2.x. legally, but the moderators removed it because it wasn't a technical question. The question and its answer are bundled in [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) though. You may want to read that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was having older version of Adobe Reader (Version : X), which doesn't have the capability to save user entered data. Upgrading Adobe Reader to DC version seems to have fixed my problem where I can now save the filled in form data. Just trying to document here so that it can be useful for the fellows who may be are running into similar situations.